# wget command response 403 Forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I am trying to use wget command on ubuntu but the response getting is 403 Forbidden

below are my commands:

wget https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/20417/pg20417.txt

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

Comment: Do you use a proxy server to access the internet ?